# Инструменты разработки для MS-DOS

Tags: c, ассемблер, dos

Хочу попробовать что-то написать под ms-dos ради лучшего познания систем реального времени, да и ассемблер подучу ибо пока плоховато знаю.
В интернете сразу находятся TurboC tasm и некоторые другие продукты, хотел бы узнать у людей знающих разработку под ms-dos не понаслышке какие ide для C и ассемблера, отладчики, компиляторы, диалект ассемблера рационально сейчас использовать?

Comment: Отладчик - Turbo Debugger. IDE вы вряд ли найдете.

Comment: Ну тогда текстовый редактор под dos с поддержкой подсветки синтаксиса, такие есть?

Comment: Текстовый редактор - edit.com. Для асма наверняка ничего не будет с подсветкой, а так - Turbo C, там может и подсветка была...

Comment: @Виталий -  а Вы для полного погружения хотите и разрабатывать прямо в ДОСе? Просто возьмите обычный Virtual Box, установите туда себе дос, а разработку ведите на своей машине. Тут будет сильно проще найти редактор на любой вкус. А вот с ДОСом можно связываться по shared folder.

Comment: А что насчет ассемблера? Tasm использовать?

Comment: @KoVadim, так не интересно, я люблю извращения.

Comment: в этом случае, зачем Вам подсветка синтакса и редактор вообще?

Comment: Я хотел бы просто попробовать именно так как это делали в те времена.

Comment: Попробуйте пакет [flat assembler](http://flatassembler.net/download.php) для dos скачать, там и редактор свой есть, вроде бы даже с подсветкой.

Comment: Рационально? Боюсь, что никакие.
Но вот у меня есть до сих пор теплые воспоминания о работе в Borland C/C++ 3.xx http://www.opita.net/node/69
Можно скачать и попробовать поработать - среда очень даже полноценная.

Comment: @Виталий Возьмите простую среду тут - https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4DL1cHu0gJjY0RHZWFYNFdUT1k&usp=sharing - раскопал со времен своей молодости среду под TASM. насколько помню, надо запустить init для конфигурирования - не пользовался все же уже даже не скажу сколько лет... Это именно так, как мы работали в 1992 году :)

Comment: @Виталий А зачем для асма подсветка синтаксиса. там подсвечивать особо нечего. В те времена обычно использовал встроенный в norton commander редактор. Сборка программы обычным bat'ником. отладчик AFD или тупо отладочная печать

Comment: Совсем обленились, среду разработки им подавай. А как вам первоначальное написание на листке бумаги и базовая отладка в собственной памяти, воображая себя процессором. А то когда комп доступен 3 часа в неделю надо было максимально много сделать не имея комп перед собой. вот так будет наиболее близко к временам MS DOS ... :) И еще 5и дюймовый дисковод раздобудьте, надо же программы на чем то хранить :)

Comment: Borland C 3.1 (или 3.0) - хорошая среда.